# Map and Set in Java- problem with printing

Tags: java, printing, set, maps

I created the following and ultimately I would like it to write to me like this:

```
Europe
     Poland
        Warsaw
        Cracow
     Spain
        Barcelona
        Madrid
```

What's the easiest way to do this?

I can only separate Europe, and I have the rest in one line

```
    Set<String> cities=new HashSet<>();
    Map<String, Set<String>> citiesForCountry=new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Map<String, Set<String>>> countriesForContinent=new HashMap<>();
    cities.add("Warsaw");
    cities.add("Cracow");
    citiesForCountry.put("Poland", cities);
    cities=new HashSet<>();
    cities.add("Barcelona");
    cities.add("Madrid");
    citiesForCountry.put("Spain", cities);
    countriesForContinent.put("Europe", citiesForCountry);


    String space= "    ";
    System.out.println(countriesForContinent.keySet());
    System.out.println(space+ countriesForContinent.values());
```

Comment: Try to imagine how your code should work, write it as pseudo-code and then try to write it as actual code. When you will face some *specific* problem ask about it, like "how to iterate over map entries?" or "how to iterate over set elements?".

Comment: The `println` method prints the value you pass into it in one line and then adds a new line after it. Currently, you're printing all the values in one println. Consider using a loop over the `values()` of the map

Comment: BTW `Map<String, Map<String, Set<String>>>` looks like a code-smell. Wouldn't you prefer to work with something more like `List<Continet> continents = ...` where `Continent` has its own `Set<Country> countries` and each `Country` has its own `Set<String> cities`? This way you could easily write code like `for(each continent from allContinents){print continent name; for(each country from current continent) {print country name with one indentation; for (each city from current country) { print each city with 2 indentations} } }` ofc this is pseudo-code, your task is to convert it into real one.